# how to redirect to login page in scala, if user not logged in?

Tags: scala, playframework, session-variables, session-cookies, playframework-2.2

i am new at scala play framework.i want to redirect to the login page if session values not find and users tries the url of home or any other page.hope you understand what i want.In scala play framework if user tries to go to the home page without login then it shows an error.i don't want to show these errors, i want that user automatically redirect to the login page.thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a solution, but doesn't know that its a right approach or not.

```
def generalAccountSetting()=Action{
implicit request=>
  try{
    val result=User.getResult(session.get("userId").get)// this makes exception, if user not logged in.
  if(!result.isEmpty){
    Ok(html.general(result(0)))
  }
  else
    Ok(html.onError())
  }catch{
   case e:Exception=>
            println(e.toString)
            Redirect("/").withNewSession
  }

}//end generalAccountSetting
```

#### EDIT:after 5 days

*got a better way*

```
def generalAccountSetting() = Action { implicit request =>
try{
    session.get("userId").map{user=>
        val result=User.getResult(session.get("userId").get)// this makes exception, if user not logged in.
  if(!result.isEmpty){
Ok(html.general(result(0)))
}
else
Ok(html.onError())
    }.getOrElse{
        Redirect("/")
      }
}catch{
    case e=>
    Ok(html.onError())
}
 }//end generalAccountSetting
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make usage of [Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal) to check at *every* request if required session value exists and redirect to the login page in other case.

That's quite easy to achieve, anyway can't show you Scala sample as I'm using Java only, in my case simplest approach is (simplified for demo):

```
@Override
public Action onRequest(Http.Request request, Method method) {

    if (request.cookie("logged_user") == null && !request.path().startsWith("/login")) {
        return new Action.Simple() {
            public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
                return temporaryRedirect("/login");
            }
        };
    }

    return super.onRequest(request, method);
}
```

Comment: please check my answer,my solution works, but tell me its a right approach or not?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at play docs [www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaSecurity](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaSecurity) here you have example how to use Secured trait to perform Authorization

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it and it is a matter of choice. Though I have made my personal one where session management is loosely coupled.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Logger

/**
 * Trait to convert cookie to something which makes sense literally.
 * @tparam A Session Object type.
 */
trait DecryptSession[A] {

  /**
   * Retrieve the connected user email.
   */
  protected final def username(request: RequestHeader): Option[String] = request.session.get(sessionId)

  /**
   * Takes the parameter obtained from cookie (after decyphering) and then converts it to type A
   * @param the string obtained from Session Cookie
   * @return Left(err) err: is the error string if something is wrong with Cookie. Right(Option[A])
   */
  protected def fromSession(param: String): Either[String, A]

  /**
   * Saves a session object and returns a Session tuple containign key-value pair of
   * Cookie-key and Cookie-value. This can be directly used for result.
   * Example:
   * {{{
   *    Ok("hey").withNewSession(toSession(userObject))
   *  }}}
   */
  def toSession(param: A): (String, String)

  protected val sessionId = "sessionId";
}

/**
 * Provide security features
 */
trait WebSecurity[A] extends DecryptSession[A] {

  import play.api.mvc.BodyParsers._
  import views._

  /**
   * Redirect to login if the user in not authorized.
   */
  private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) =
    play.api.mvc.Results.Redirect(controllers.routes.Assets.at("public/signup.html"))


  /**
   * Checks if the user is a authenticated/logged in User. If yes, then executes "f" body.
   * Else does action based on onAuthFailure.withNewSession
   *
   * @tparam T the content type
   * @param bodyParser the `BodyParser` to use to parse the request body
   * @param onAuthFailure function used to generate alternative result if the user is not authenticated
   * @param f Body. It gets User and request object as arguments and returns a Result. Just like any other Action
   */
  def GeneralFilter[T](bodyParser: BodyParser[T] = parse.anyContent)(onAuthFailure: RequestHeader => SimpleResult)(f: => A => Request[T] => Result) =
    Security.Authenticated(username, onAuthFailure) { id =>
      Action(bodyParser) { request =>
        fromSession(id) match {
          case Left(err) => {
            Logger.error(s"A session value from a request is inconsistent to protocol: $err . Session in header: $id")
            onAuthFailure(request).withNewSession
          }
          case Right(x) => f(x)(request)
        }
      }
    }
}

sealed trait DashboardSecurity extends WebSecurity[User] {

  import play.api.mvc.Results.Redirect

  override protected def fromSession(param: String): Either[String, User] = Users.getUser(param).map(Right(_)).getOrElse(Left("Invalid Session Id"))
  }

  def toSession(param: User): (String, String) = (sessionId, param.id.toString)

}

object Dashboard extends Controller with DashboardSecurity {
/**
   * Home page of the User
   */
  def homePage = GeneralFilter()(loginPage) { id =>
    implicit request =>
      Ok("Welcome home - " + id)
  }
}
```

Above in `homePage`, if the user is not authenticated, then he is directly redirected to loginPage